# Space separated string to create dynamic Sql query

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a space separated string as parameter to my SP. I need to split the strings and compare each one against a column in the database along with wildcard and return the results.

For example:

I have CompanyName 'ABC DataServices Pvt Ltd' I need to split the string by 'space' and compare each word with database field company name with an `OR` condition.

Something like this:

```
select * 
from CompanyTable 
where companyname like '%ABC%' 
    or companyname like '%DataServices%' 
    or companyname like '%Pvt%' 
    or companyname like '%Ltd%'
```

Can some one help me out to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7938/SQL-User-Defined-Function-to-Parse-a-Delimited-Str) SQL User Defined Function to Parse a Delimited String helpful .

For Quick Solution use this ,

```
SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE('ABC DataServices Pvt Ltd', ' ', '.'), 2) // return DataServices
```

PARSENAME takes a string and splits it on the period character. It takes a number as it's second argument, and that number specifies which segment of the string to return (working from back to front).
you can put the index you want in place of 2 in above like

```
SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE('ABC DataServices Pvt Ltd', ' ', '.'), 3)  --return Pvt
```

declare a string in your store procedure and use set this value to it. use where you want.
The only problem is when the string already contains a period. One thing should be noted that `PARSENAME` only expects four parts, so using a string with more than four parts causes it to return `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString] 
( 
@string NVARCHAR(MAX), 
@delimiter CHAR(1) 
) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(splitdata NVARCHAR(MAX) 
) 
BEGIN 
DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
    IF @end = 0  
        SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1

    INSERT INTO @output (splitdata)  
    VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)) 
    SET @start = @end + 1 
    SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)

END 
RETURN 
END
```

And use it like this:

```
select * from dbo.fnSplitString('Querying SQL Server','')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this.

First in your parameter's value replace space with comma (,) and then replace comma with desired where condition like this -

```
DECLARE @companyname VARCHAR(1000)
    ,@where VARCHAR(max)

SET @companyname = 'ABC DataServices Pvt Ltd'
SET @companyname = replace(@companyname, ' ', ', ')

SELECT @where = 'companyname like ''%' + 
REPLACE(@companyname, ', ', '%'' OR companyname like ''%') + '%'''

PRINT @where

PRINT ('SELECT * FROM CompanyTable WHERE' + @where)
--EXEC ('SELECT * FROM CompanyTable WHERE' + @where)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will scale to any number of search terms and does not require dynamic SQL.

```
declare @a table (w varchar(50)) -- holds original string
declare @b table (s varchar(50)) -- holds parsed string

insert into @a -- load string into temp table
values ('ABC DataServices Pvt Ltd')

--parse string as XML
;WITH Vals AS (
        SELECT  w,
                CAST('<d>' + REPLACE(w, ' ', '</d><d>') + '</d>' AS XML) XmlColumn
        FROM    @a
)


--Insert results to parsed string
insert into @b
SELECT  
        C.value('.','varchar(max)') ColumnValue
FROM    Vals
CROSS APPLY Vals.XmlColumn.nodes('/d') AS T(C)


--Join on results
select * from companytable
join @b b on b.s like '%'+companyname+'%'
```

Comment: XML parser shamelessly stolen from here http://stackoverflow.com/a/4267183/2587452.  If you need more performance, you can use a temp table for the split results and index it.