# Compare two SUBSTRINGS in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, substring, charindex

I have the following test code:

```
DECLARE
     @Str1 VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Hello World'
    ,@Str2 VARCHAR(MAX) = 'World Hello'

SELECT CHARINDEX(@Str1, @Str2)
```

The select statement returns zero because it takes the whole **@Str1** and tries to find it within **@Str2**.

How can I make the search compare sub-strings?

In other word, I want the search to see if a substring of **@Str1** can be found as substring in **@Str2**

Comment: Any substring? As in 'w' or 'he' or ' '?

Comment: Good question, I would say words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just splitting on spaces what you'd do is split the string and then search for each split word and get the char index of that.

Here's a quick example:

```
DECLARE
     @Str1 VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Hello World'
    ,@Str2 VARCHAR(MAX) = 'World Hello'


   DECLARE @substring VARCHAR(MAX)
   DECLARE c CURSOR FOR 
   SELECT Item = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')
      FROM 
      ( 
        SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
          + REPLACE(@Str1, ' ', '</i><i>') 
          + '</i>').query('.')
      ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
    OPEN c
    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @substring
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    BEGIN
        SELECT CHARINDEX(@substring, @str2)
    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @substring
    END
    CLOSE c
    DEALLOCATE c
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use instr (which calculates length using characters defined by input character set) to find if the substring exist in other.

```
select * from tablename
where instr(upper(str1),upper(str2)) > 0
--This would give if a str1 exist in the str2
or upper(str1) = upper(str2);--This would be same string
```

Comment: OP tagged SQL Server ... instr()

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the answer but cannot comment :-(

Question: What type of substring would you be looking for. A substring could be the entire word "Hello" but also just the letters "llo" of even "l". I would assume you mean to see if any of the **words** in @Str1 are contained in @Str2.

You would then use a split function such as found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266957/how-to-split-string-and-save-into-an-array-in-t-sql) to first split the @Str1 into a list and then create a loop over that table to use the CHARINDEX to find any substring.

But all of this depends on your definition of "substring"

Comment: Thank you, I would say words because if I open the door to any substring, I think it will make it complex for nothing.